# Is it possible to know which of two submit buttons are clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am thinking of having something like this:

```
 @if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
 {
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
 }
 else
 {
    <input id="continueButton" type="submit" value="Continue to next page" />
 }
```

Then in controller is it possible to know which button it is getting called from?
I originally had my controller method working with the first button, now adding a second button with different functionality, wanted to see if using the same method I can determine which button was clicked ?  and if it is not possible this way, then what do you suggest?

Comment: You can just give the buttons a `name="button"` and add a parameter `string button` to you POST method (the value of the parameter will be either `"Update stuff"` or `"Continue to next page"`). There is no need for hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without extra information. I would likely split them up rather than have two submit buttons for the same form doing two different things but if you really want to go down that road one way would be to add an additional posted variable that tells you which was clicked.

```
@if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="submitStyle" value="update"/>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
}
else
{
    <input type="hidden" name="submitStyle" value="continue"/>
    <input id="continueButton" type="submit" value="Continue to next page" />
}
```

To answer your additional question. Either you can add this variable to your model posted back or add it as an additional parameter.

```
// Where "MyModel" has a public property "SubmitStyle"
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)

// Or an int, string, whatever type of parameter you want/need.
// In my example it was a string so...
public ActionResult MyAction(string submitStyle/*, <other params...>*/)
```

Comment: thanks, and who would I utilize it in the controller side?

Comment: Thank you, I am applying it to my code now to see how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a hidden field. Not ideal solution, but does the job.

```
 @if(Model.ShowSubmitButton)
 {
    <input type="hidden" name="buttonClicked" value="1">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Update stuff" />
 }
 else
 {
    <input type="hidden" name="buttonClicked" value="2">
    <input id="continueButton" type="submit" value="Continue to next page" />
 }
```

In your controller you would accept it as:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyObject myobj, int buttonClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant way (tested only on chrome yet), define two inputs

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="Action"/>
<input type="submit" value="Prev" name="Action"/>
```

Now in you input model in controller put model defined like this:

```
public class MyModelDto
{
    // other properties
    public MyCustomAction Action { get; set; }
}
```

Where the

```
public enum MyCustomAction
{
  Next=0,
  Prev=1
}
```

Now check the value of action.